# Why 'init' hook doesn't work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add an action to **'init'** hook, but when I open any page I don't get the result which is defined in the callback.

Could you say what to do?

*(permissions to the file system are present. I located a code, which is inside the callback, directly into **activate** method and it worked)*

```
class MyPlugin
{
    public function activate()
    {
        add_action('init', function() {
            $file = fopen(__DIR__.'myFile.txt', "w");
            fwrite($file, 'it works');
            fclose($file);
        });
    }

$myPluggin = new MyPlugin();

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($myPluggin, 'activate'));
```

P.S.: When I call `do_action('init')` manually it works. But how to get it work automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question, (it's written [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)):

> only two hooks are fired after the plugin's activation hook:
>   'activated_plugin' and 'shutdown'